# Chef recipe for interactive install

Tags: chef

I'm new to chef and trying to set up an Ubuntu VM for testing by installing our product automatically. I am able to download the .tgz, extract it and execute the installer using a bash resource.

I the problem I've encountered is that our install script enforces a EULA check for the command line install. It has something similar to the following in a shell script:

```
# various statements and input to expect from stdin
echo "You must accept our EULA to install the software"

read ENTER
more EULA.txt

echo "Do you accept the EULA?"
# additional input expected from stdin
```

I can easily add the expected input from standard by using a response file and kicking off the install with `./install.sh < response.txt`, but this stops working once `more` is executed. The more command doesn't see the input from the response file and still expects a 'q' to quit the command before accepting the eula.

What is the proper way to execute such an install automatically using chef? Beyond simply re-writing the install.sh script to ignore the EULA line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also redirect the output somewhere. `more` will simply display the entire file without pausing and then exit if standard output is not a terminal.

For example:

```
 ./install.sh < response.txt | cat
```

Though you really should be using something like `expect` for scenarios like this.

Comment: Thanks, this is closer to what I need, the `more` output is sent no longer blocking me, but it looks like my input from response.txt is completely eaten up before the more command starts. Once the text from `more` is completed, I have no more input for the install script.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying expect. Never used it before, so it is going slowly.

Comment: After playing with it, `expect` solved the problem. Thanks.